# Path connectivity: why can I assume that the interval $[a,b]$ for $\gamma$ can be chosen as $[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology

The definition of path connectivity given in my textbook is: $X$ is path connected if $\forall \ x,y \in X$ there exist a curve $\gamma: [a,b] \rightarrow X$ with $\gamma(a)=x$ and $\gamma(b)=y$ that is continuous.

Now reading articles on the web, (https://simomaths.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/topology-path-connected-spaces/), the interval $[a,b]$ is stated as $[0,1]$.

How can I assume that $[a,b]$ can be chosen as $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Hint:Homeomorphic !

Comment: I think because you can always map [a,b] to [0,1], without loss of generality.

Comment: Is it neccesary to use a homeomorphism ? Isn't it enough just to use a mapping $\pi:[0,1] \rightarrow [a,b]$ with $\pi(0) = a$ and $\pi(1) =b$ and $\pi$ is continuous ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the function $h:[a,b]\to [0,1]$ defined by $$h(x) = \frac{x-a}{b-a}$$
Notice that this function is a homeomorphism, so $\gamma$ is a continuous curve iff $\gamma\circ h$ is a continuous curve.

Comment: Is it neccesary to use a homeomorphism ? Isn't it enough just to use a mapping $\pi:[0,1] \rightarrow [a,b]$ with $\pi(0) = a$ and $\pi(1) =b$ and $\pi$ is continuous ?

Answer (score 1):

Because any $[a,b]$ with $a\neq b$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. So by replacing $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow X$ by $\gamma\circ\phi:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ where $\phi$ denotes a homeomorphism from $[0,1]$ to $[a,b]$

Comment: Is it neccesary to use a homeomorphism ? Isn't it enough just to use a mapping $\pi:[0,1] \rightarrow [a,b]$ with $\pi(0) = a$ and $\pi(1) =b$ and $\pi$ is continuous ?